# Right aligning last nav menu pop up with CSS

Tags: css

I'm looking to right align the "pop-up" menu of my nav structure to the right edge of the div. Currently, it is "popping out" of the div. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

```css
 .main-navigation {


   background-color: #2f9fa8;


 }


 .subMenu li:hover > a {


   color: #e3d174;


   text-decoration: underline;


 }


 #GeneralInfo {


   width: 160px;


   padding-top: 5px;


   padding-left: 20px;


 }


 #Registration {


   width: 200px;


   padding-top: 5px;


   padding-left: 20px;


 }


 #ScientificPrograms {


   width: 175px;


   padding-top: 5px;


   padding-left: 20px;


 }


 #SpecialEvents {


   width: 110px;


   padding-top: 5px;


   padding-left: 20px;


 }


 #Careers {


   width: 70px;


   padding-top: 5px;


   padding-left: 20px;


 }


 #Exhibits {


   width: 90px;


   padding-top: 5px;


   padding-left: 20px;


 }


 .subMenu {


   width: 200px;


 }


 #navMenu ul,


 #navMenu {


   list-style-type: none;


   margin: 0;


   padding: 0;


 }


 .nav > li > a {


   display: block;


   height: 100%;


   color: #FFFFFF;


   text-decoration: none;


   padding: 0;


   font-size: 14px;


   font-weight: 800;


   outline: none;


 }


 .nav > li > a:hover {


   display: block;


   height: 100%;


   padding: 0;


   color: #FFFFFF;


   text-decoration: none;


   background: #2f9fa8;


 }


 .nav > li {


   padding: 0;


   float: left;


   height: 30px;


   font-family: Arial, sans-serif;


   font-size: 14px;


   background-color: #2f9fa8;


 }


 .nav li {


   position: relative;


 }


 .nav li > ul {


   position: absolute;


   display: none;


   border-bottom: 0;


   z-index: 9999;


 }


 .nav li > ul > li > a {


   text-decoration: none;


   color: #FFFFFF;


   font-weight: 600;


   display: block;


   background: #2f9fa8;


   text-shadow: none;


   padding: 5px 3px 5px 10px;


   text-indent: -7px;


 }


 .nav li:hover > ul {


   display: block;


 }
```

```html
<nav class="main-navigation">
  <ul id="navMenu" class="nav">


    <li id="GeneralInfo"><a class="gradient" href="#">General Information</a>
      <ul class="subMenu" id="sub-GeneralInfo">
        <li><a href='#'>Annual Meeting</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>San Diego, CA</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Supporters</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Just for the Media</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Volunteer</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Awards and Fellowships</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>FAQs</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Forms</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Events and Maps</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Meeting Requests</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Visa Information</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Transportation</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Ride Share Program</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Restaurants</a>
        </li>
        <li class='last'><a href='#'>Top Reasons to Attend</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </li>



    <li id="Registration"><a class="gradient" href="#">Registration &amp; Housing</a>
      <ul class="subMenu" id="sub-Registration">
        <li><a href='#'>Online Registration</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Registration Information</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Housing Reservations</a>
        </li>
        <li class='last'><a href='#'>Room Share Program</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>



    <li id="ScientificPrograms"><a class="gradient" href="#">Scientific Programs</a>
      <ul class="subMenu" id="sub-ScientificPrograms">
        <!--<li><a href='#'>Submit a Session Proposal</a></li>-->
        <li><a href='#'>Submit an Abstract</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Mobile Event App</a>
        </li>
        <!--<li><a href='#'>Scientific Session Index</a></li>-->
        <!--<li><a href='#'>Abstract Author Index</a></li>-->
        <!--<li><a href='#'>Abstract Keyword Index</a></li>-->
        <li><a href='#'>Continuing Education</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Continuing Medical Education</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Scientific Sessions</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Thematic Approach</a>
        </li>
        <!--<li><a href='#'>Scientific ePosters</a></li>-->
        <li class='last'><a href='#'>Presentation Instructions</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>



    <li id="SpecialEvents"><a class="gradient" href="#">Special Events</a>
      <ul class="subMenu" id="sub-SpecialEvents">
        <li><a href='#'>Outreach</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Featured Sessions</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Social Events</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Student and Postdoc Scholar Events</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Satellite Meetings</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Meeting Requests</a>
        </li>
        <li class='last'><a href='#'>Virtual Global Gallery Posters</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>



    <li id="Careers"><a class="gradient" href="#">Careers</a>
      <ul class="subMenu" id="sub-Careers">
        <li><a href='#'>Career Sessions</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Career Resources and Development Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class='last'><a href='#'>Job Bank</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>



    <li id="Exhibits"><a class="gradient" href="#">Exhibits</a>
      <ul class="subMenu" id="sub-Exhibits">
        <li><a href='#'>ToxExpo</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Exhibitor Listing</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Exhibitor-Hosted Session Application</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Exhibitor-Hosted Sessions</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Support Opportunities</a>
        </li>
        <li class='last'><a href='#'>Supporter Listing</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

You can fint it also in [codepen](http://codepen.io/trevoray/pen/qEMMZb/z%60)

Comment: tks Pete! how do i credit your answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to right align the popup menu `.nav li ul` to the container "trigger" menu element then you should simply add `right: 0;` to `.nav li > ul`

Like:

```
.nav li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    border-bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```